# Highlight cells with spaces before and after values

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a small macro for highlighting cells with more than one spaces in names. Now I have noticed that there are also values with space before the name and after. How to edit my current code so it will highlight cells also like "    Word  word" or "Word word" or "  Word word  "

So the only one that will pass the validation is case when everything is properly written like "Word word"

Here is my current code:

```
Sub MarkMoreThanOneSpace()

Dim Cell
Dim rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A2:L" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each Cell In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cell, "*  *") > 0 Then

        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    Exit Sub
    End

    End If

    Next Cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `WorksheetFunction.Trim()` function

loop through cells with values only to shorten time

don't exit at the first finding, or you'll miss all the others

and don't use `End`!

```
Sub MarkMoreThanOneSpace()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A2:L" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell.Value) <> cell.Value Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Also, you can try `Regex`, but that may be overkill.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cell.Value, "*  *") > 0 _
    Or Left$(Cell.Value,1) = " " _
    Or Right$(cell.Value,1) = " " Then
```

Furthermore, you can get rid of VBA altogether and place these formulas in conditional formatting rules.